# How do I skip non-parsable text with antlr4?

Tags: antlr, grammar, context-free-grammar, antlr4, regular-language

I have been trying to create a parser with antlr4 for a small templating system that I need. 
The template is just as you can see some functions that always starts with an equal number of '{{' and '}}' and within that the function is defined that will be pased and executed and should replace the whole thing with that function result.

The problem is that I want to leave all the other text outside the functions alone and just parse what I am defining. Right now STRING is not matching or leaving the other text alone. I want to skip or ignore all fulltext besides the functions defined.

Ultimately the goal is to replace the entire {{..}} part with the result of the function.

Is there a way to skip all the other text?

Here is the sample text:

```
allkinds of text $#@ {{getMetaSelf option1}} blabla bla {{getEnv test test}} now repeat something: {{repeatPerInstance test ','}} 
this will get repeated. sub functions are possible here now: {{getMetaInstance option1}} blabla {{endrepeat}} more text.
```

This is what I have managed so far:

```
parse: EOF | (functions | STRING)* ;

functions : '{{' func STRING*
          ;

func : getterFunctions
     | 'repeatPerInstance ' KEYWORD ( ' ' delimiter )? '}}' ( '{{' ( getterFunctions | repeatSubFunctions ) )*  '{{endrepeat}}'
     ;

getterFunctions : 'getEnv ' KEYWORD ' ' KEYWORD '}}'
                | 'getMetaSelf ' metaoptions '}}'
                ;

repeatSubFunctions : 'getEnvRole' KEYWORD '}}'
                   | 'getMetaInstance' metaoptions '}}'
                   ;


metaoptions : 'option1'
            | 'option2'
            | 'option3'
            | 'option4'
            ;

delimiter : '\'' ',' '\'' ;

STRING : . +? ;

KEYWORD : [0-9A-Za-z\-\_]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multi-mode lexer for this. Since the file starts with freeform text, the default mode will be the one to contain your `TEXT` rule.

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;

TEXT
  : ( ~'{'
    | '{' {_input.LA(1) != '{'}?
    )+
  ;

OPEN_TAG
  : '{{' -> pushMode(InTag)
  ;

mode InTag;

  END_TAG
    : '}}' -> popMode
    ;

  // other rules for tokens inside of {{ ... }} go here
```

Comment: Thanks! I just don't know how to test/implement this though. When I compile this with antlr4 I get a classnotfound for the grammar parser. How do I test this by parsing a file or text?

Answer (score 0):

Btw.:

The following line seems strange since it accepts `STRING`s *after* the function, which is probably not was was intended:

functions : '{{' func STRING*
          ;

I'd also model the functions this way (not tested), which groups the `{{` `}}`:

```
parse: (function | STRING)* EOF ;


function : '{{' 
            functionBody
            '}}'
          ;

functionBody 
     : getterFunctions
     | 'repeatPerInstance ' KEYWORD ( ' ' delimiter )? '}}' ( '{{' ( getterFunctions | repeatSubFunctions ) '}}')*  '{{endrepeat'
     ;

getterFunctions : 'getEnv ' KEYWORD ' ' KEYWORD 
                | 'getMetaSelf ' metaoptions 
                ;

repeatSubFunctions : 'getEnvRole' KEYWORD 
                   | 'getMetaInstance' metaoptions 
                   ;
```